# Validações em form no HTML5 se comporta de forma diferente no Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, html5, validação

Estava tentando procurar um título melhor para esta pergunta, mas eu ainda não sei direito como explicar, mas vamos lá.

Eu tenho um simples formulário com três campos, se eu errar um deles será mostrado um tooltip falando que o campo precisa ser preenchido corretamente, até ai tudo bem, eu corrijo as informações no form e as envio, quando eu envio as validações flegam todos os inputs de vermelho parecendo que eu havia submetido duas vezes o form, este comportamento só aconteceu no Firefox tanto para Macbook quanto para Windows, testei na versão 46.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var form = document.getElementById("Form");
var time = document.getElementById("Time");
form.onsubmit = function() {
  console.log('test');
  this.reset();
  time.focus();
  return false;
};
```

```html
<form id="Form">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>New Item</legend>
    <label for="Time">Time:</label>
    <input type="text" required="" autofocus="" pattern="[0-9]{1,2}" placeholder="Time spend" name="Time" id="Time">
    <label for="Type">Action:</label>
    <select required="" name="Type" id="Type">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option>Run</option>
      <option>Swimming</option>
      <option>Bike</option>
      <option>Drink</option>
      <option>Eat</option>
      <option>Crossfit</option>
      <option>Yoga</option>
    </select>
    <label for="Date">Date:</label>
    <input type="text" required="" pattern="(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d" placeholder="dd/mm/aaaa" name="Date" id="Date">
    <button class="add" type="submit">Add</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Link no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gabrielr47/ng95boak/1/)

Comment: É porquê a propriedade **required** é entendida de formas diferentes pelos browsers.

Comment: Você quer saber o que está ocorrendo, como arrumar ou os dois?

Comment: @Randrade os dois, entender o problema e saber como solucionar haha

Comment: Não sei se entendi a pergunta, caso não tenha chegado no ponto que queria, basta informar que melhoro a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Cada navegador possui uma forma diferente de tratar as validações no HTML5.

o Google Chrome trabalha com validações initárias, ou seja, ele irá validar cada campo até chegar no final. 
O Firefox e IE não, eles validam todos os campos do form antes de retornar a mensagem.

O que você comenta em sua pergunta está relacionado com esse código em específico:

```
form.onsubmit = function() {
  console.log('test');
  this.reset();
  time.focus();
  return false;
};
```

Em nenhum dos navegadores o `form` está sendo enviado, pois em seu código você está "resetando" o formulário (`this.reset();`) e falando que o formulário não está válido (`return false;`).

Não sei se esse código é apenas para demonstração, ou o que você espera com ele, mas você pode retirar o `return` que ele será enviado.

Sobre a questão da validação, você não pode alterar os comportamentos dos navegadores, o que pode fazer é realizar validações de formas diferentes, criando as suas próprias e mostrando da forma que desejar.

Comment: Eu não coloquei no código, mas antes do this.reset eu faço um serialize do form e envio para um metodo x. o return false é para não atualizar a página, comportamento semelhante do  e.preventDefault(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462143/prevent-default-on-form-submit-jquery

Comment: Ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Então, da mesma forma. O Firefox entende que não foi validado os campos, pois o retorno do `form` é false.

Comment: Você fez o teste? se você digitar tudo certo ele funciona, agora se você digitar um errado e depois corrigir ele e enviar eles são resetados e marcados de vermelho como se tivesse clicado duas vezes.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Fiz sim. O que acontece que ele trabalha com [estados de validações](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation). Se você digitar um errado, o estado do `form` fica `Invalid`. Como você retorna `false` e não deixa validar novamente, o estado continua `invalid`.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues [olhe este exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ng95boak/2/) onde eu alterei a mensagem de erro. Veja como eles se comportam, acho que irá entender melhor.